# Generalizing Fibonacci sequence with SICStus Prolog

Tags: prolog, fibonacci, sicstus-prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to find a solution for a query on a generalized Fibonacci sequence (GFS). The query is: are there any GFS that have 885 as their 12th number? The initial 2 numbers may be restricted between 1 and 10.

I already found the solution to find the Nth number in a sequence that starts at (1, 1) in which I explicitly define the initial numbers. Here is what I have for this:

```
fib(1, 1).
fib(2, 1).

fib(N, X) :-
    N #> 1,
    Nmin1 #= N - 1,
    Nmin2 #= N - 2,
    fib(Nmin1, Xmin1),
    fib(Nmin2, Xmin2),
    X #= Xmin1 + Xmin2.
```

For the query mentioned I thought the following would do the trick, in which I reuse the fib method without defining the initial numbers explicitly since this now needs to be done dynamically:

```
fib(N, X) :-
    N #> 1,
    Nmin1 #= N - 1,
    Nmin2 #= N - 2,
    fib(Nmin1, Xmin1),
    fib(Nmin2, Xmin2),
    X #= Xmin1 + Xmin2.

fib2 :-
    X1 in 1..10,
    X2 in 1..10,
    fib(1, X1),
    fib(2, X2),
    fib(12, 885).
```

... but this does not seem to work.

Is it not possible this way to define the initial numbers, or am I doing something terribly wrong? I'm not asking for the solution, but any advice that could help me solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nice problem. Firstly try to get rid of exponential recursion; it will kill your code. Try to use accumulators for that.

Answer (score 5):

Under SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

fib(A,B,N,X):-
    N #> 0,
    N0 #= N-1,
    C #= A+B,
    fib(B,C,N0,X).
fib(A,B,0,A).

task(A,B):-
    A in 1..10,
    B in 1..10,
    fib(A,B,11,885).
```

Comment: @CookieMonster, prolog tends to represent some searches in a more natural way than some other languages (ex `max(X, L):- member(X, L), not((member(Y, L), Y > X)).`). What you mean under "labeling"?

Comment: @CookieMonster, ahh... that's specific of SICSTUS Prolog. I never used that one. Prefer YAP and for samples SWI. In both all free placeholders are printed.

Comment: @CookieMonster, I use Yap 6.2.2. On query `?- (X=2;X=3),Y is X*2.` it gives me `X = 2,` `Y = 4`. I can press `;` and get alternative. I use interactive mode (i.e. run `yap` without any additional options). Maybe that's the difference

Comment: @CookieMonster, yes you are right to get solution you need to call `task(A,B), label([A,B])`. In both SWI-Prolog and YAP. Without that it just prints constraints. BTW, in Curry you can simply write `C=A+B` and it will be suspended/postponed (co-routines-like) until `A` and `B` bound to something.

Answer (score 1):

Define a predicate gfs(X0, X1, N, F) where X0 and X1 are the values for the base cases 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're doing something terribly wrong...
When you call `fib(1, X1)`, the variable X1 is the number that the function `fib` will return, in this case, it will be 1, because of the base case `fib(1, 1).`.

Comment: The base case is not defined when I call fib2. fib is defined, but without the explicit initial numbers. This is probably confusing in my question, I'll update it.

Comment: Okay, I'll have another look :)

Answer (score 0):

Without the base cases, fib/2 has no solution; no matter how you call it in fib2. 
Note: if you use recursion, you need at least one base case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `fib(N,F1,F2)` so you'll be able to replace `fib(Nmin1, Xmin1)` and `fib(Nmin2, Xmin2)` with simple `fib(Nmin2, Xmin2, Xmin1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a solution in the strict sense but I will share it never the less. Probably the only gain is to show, that this does neither need a computer nor a calculator to be solved. If you know the trick it can be done on a bearmat.

If F_n ist the n-th Term of the ordinary Fibo-sequence, starting with F_1=F_2=1, then the n-th Term of the generalized sequence will be G_n = F_{n-2}*a+F_{n-1}*b.
Define F_{-1}=1, F_0 = 0

(Indeed, by induction

- G_1 = F_{-1}*a+F_0*b = 1*a+0*b=a
- G_2 = F_0 * a + F_1 * b = 0*a + 1*b = b
- G_{n+1} = F_{n-1}*a + F_n*b = (F_{n-3} + F_{n-2} )a + (F_{n-2} + F_{n-1})*b = G_n + G_{n-1}

)

Thus G_12 = F_10 * a + F_11 * b = 55a + 89b.

Now you can either search for solutions to the equation 55a + 89b = 885 with your computer

OR

do the math:

Residues mod 11 ([explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_%28jargon%29)):

55a + 89b = 0 + 88b + b = b; 885 = 880 + 5 = 80*11 + 5 = 5

So b = 5 mod 11, but since 1 <= b <= 10, b really is 5. 89 * 5 = 445 and 885-445 = 440. Now, divide by 55 and get a=8.

Comment: CLP(FD) is probably not good at the algebra and inductive proof you did. But CLP(FD) would be good in finding solutions to equations such as 55*A+89*B #= 885.