# Why does this command cause a stack overflow in prolog?

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

I have the following snippet of prolog code:

```
num(0).
num(X) :- num(X1), X is X1 + 1.

fact(0,1) :-!.
fact(X,Y) :- X1 is X-1, fact(X1,Y1), !, Y is Y1 * X.

fact(X) :- num(Y), fact(Y,X).
```

Can somebody please explain why the following command causes a stack overflow? Thanks in advance.

```
fact(6).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, looking at the rules

```
  num(0).
  num(X) :- num(X1), X is X1 + 1.
```

the predicate `num(Y)` will be immediately valid for `Y = 0`.

Thus the rule

```
  fact(X) :- num(Y), fact(Y,X).
```

can be simplified as

```
  fact(X) :- fact(0,X).
```

that will find a match for `fact(0,1)`. For `X = 6`, what happens instead is, as no rule defines a predicate for `fact(0,6)`, a search is started with `fact(-1,V1)`, followed with `fact(-2,V2)` etc... until a match occurs for a `fact(-value, Var)` where the local result would be the Var found.

This cannot happen, and an infinite loop consumes the whole stack, until an error is triggered.

Comment: Perhaps you should point out to rookie that the problem you analyzed can be prevented by adding `X > 0` to the body of the 2nd clause for **fact/2**.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `fact(6)` does not terminate can be found in the following [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
?- fact(6).

num(0) :- false.
num(X) :-
   num(X1), false,
   X is X1 + 1.

fact(X) :-
   num(Y), false,
   fact(Y,X).
```

*Because* this fragment does not terminate, also your original program does not terminate. Note that the non-termination is independent of the definition of `fact/2`! At best, your program might succeed, but it will never (finitely) fail.

Consider to use [another definition of `fact/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909528/772868), which terminates also for `fact(N, 6).`