# Prolog factorial recursion

Tags: recursion, prolog, factorial

I'm having trouble understanding the following factorial program

```
fact1(0,Result) :-
    Result is 1.
fact1(N,Result) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    fact1(N1,Result1),
    Result is Result1*N.
```

When `fact1` is called nested within the second `fact1`, doesn't that mean that the the last line, `Result is Result1*N.`, is never called? Or in Prolog does the last line get executed before the recursive call?

Comment: a call is made, and when it finishes the control returns to continue with the following goal, if present. the call being to itself or not, is immaterial. a call is a call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the recursive call happens first!  It has to, or else that last clause is meaningless.  The algorithm breaks down to:

```
factorial(0) => 1
factorial(n) => factorial(n-1) * n;
```

As you can see, you need to calculate the result of the recursion before multiplying in order to return a correct value!

Your prolog implementation probably has a way to enable tracing, which would let you see the whole algorithm running.  That might help you out.

Comment: I hope you mean `factorial(0) => 1` :)

Comment: What about `factorial(-1)`? With above definition, the query `?- fact1(-1,_).` rightly fails; `factorial`, as it is, doesn't.

Answer (score 16):

BTW once you got the basic recursion understood, try to achieve tail recursion whenever possible, here it'd be:

```
factorial(N, R) :- factorial(N, 1, R).
factorial(0, R, R) :- !.
factorial(N, Acc, R) :-
    NewN is N - 1,
    NewAcc is Acc * N,
    factorial(NewN, NewAcc, R).
```

Tail recursion, unlike the recursion you used previously, allows interpreter/compiler to flush context when going on to the next step of recursion. So let's say you calculate `factorial(1000)`, your version will maintain 1000 contexts while mine will only maintain 1. That means that your version will eventually not calculate the desired result but just crash on an `Out of call stack memory` error.

You can [read more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) about it on wikipedia.

Comment: The goal `factorial(0,0)` *should* fail---it does not.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, [@m09's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9582409/4609915) is basically right about the importance of tail-recursion.

For big `N`, calculating the product differently wins! Think "binary tree", not "linear list"...

Let's try both ways and compare the runtimes. First, @m09's `factorial/2`:

```
?- time((factorial(100000,_),false)).
% 200,004 inferences, 1.606 CPU in 1.606 seconds (100% CPU, 124513 Lips)
false.
```

Next, we do it tree-style—using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`reduce/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30706698/4609915) together with [lambda expressions](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord):

```
?- time((numlist(1,100000,Xs),reduce(\X^Y^XY^(XY is X*Y),Xs,_),false)).
% 1,300,042 inferences, 0.264 CPU in 0.264 seconds (100% CPU, 4922402 Lips)
false.
```

Last, let's define and use dedicated auxiliary predicate `x_y_product/3`:

```
x_y_product(X, Y, XY) :- XY is X*Y.
```

What's to gain? Let's *ask the stopwatch*!

```
?- time((numlist(1,100000,Xs),reduce(x_y_product,Xs,_),false)).
% 500,050 inferences, 0.094 CPU in 0.094 seconds (100% CPU, 5325635 Lips)
false.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
factorial(1, 1).
factorial(N, Result) :- M is N - 1,
factorial(M, NextResult), Result is NextResult * N.
```

Comment: You should add an explanation to your answer. Code-only posts are not enough. Read [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/) about the details.

Answer (score 2):

Base case is declared. The conditions that N must be positive and multiply with previous term.

```
 factorial(0, 1).
 factorial(N, F) :- 
       N > 0, 
       Prev is N -1, 
       factorial(Prev, R), 
       F is R * N.
```

To run:

> factorial(-1,X).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way :

```
 factorial(N, F):- N<2, F=1.

 factorial(N, F) :- 
     M is N-1, 
     factorial(M,T), 
     F is N*T.
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like:

```
fact(0, 1).
fact(N, Result):-
    Next is N - 1,
    fact(Next, Recursion),
    Result is N * Recursion.
```

And a tail version would be like:

```
tail_fact(0, 1, 0).         /* when trying to calc factorial of zero */
tail_fact(0, Acc, Res):-    /* Base case of recursion, when reaches zero return Acc */
     Res is Acc.
tail_fact(N, Acc, Res):-    /* calculated value so far always goes to Acc */
     NewAcc is N * Acc,
     NewN is N - 1,
     tail_fact(NewN, NewAcc, Res).
```

So for you to call the:

non-tail recursive method: **fact(3, Result).**

tail recursive method:     **tail_fact(3, 1, Result).**

This might help ;)

Comment: `?- fact(0,1), false.` doesn't terminate. It should. Same for `?- tail_fact(0,1,0), false.`

Comment: Your are right!
`fact(0,0).`
`fact(N, R):- fact_aux(N, R).`

`fact_aux(0, 1).`
`fact_aux(N, R):- N > 0, NewN is N - 1, fact_aux(NewN, Rec), R is N * Rec. `

Comment: Somewhat better. But `?- fact(0,0).` should fail. It succeeds.

Comment: btw. this looks suspiciously similar to this previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28799827/4609915

Answer (score -1):

non-tailer recursion :

```
 fact(0,1):-!. 
   fact(X,Y):- Z=X-1,
         fact(Z,NZ),Y=NZ*X.
```

tailer recursion:

```
fact(X,F):- X>=0,fact_aux(X,F,1).
fact_aux(0,F,F):-!.
   fact_aux(X,F,Acc):- 
       NAcc=Acc*X, NX=X-1, 
    fact_aux(NX,F,NAcc).
```

Comment: Are you using [tag:visual-prolog]?

Comment: Which Prolog system are you using?

Comment: With SWI-Prolog, `?- fact(10,F).` loops and does not give an answer.

Comment: it was a problem in the stopping condition in visual prolog in get output right but doesn`t stop after 0 so makes stack overflow