# Recursively defined function of two integers in Prolog (partition function)

Tags: recursion, prolog, number-theory

I swear this isn't a homework problem.  I haven't attended classes in decades.  Once upon a time I came up with a cute recursive formula for the partition function:

```
         / 0 (k > n)
f(k, n) {  1 (k = n)
         \ p(k, n-k)+p(k+1, n) (k < n)
```

I thought to try to represent this in prolog.  This is about as far as I could get:

```
partition(N, N, 1) :- !. %% http://stackoverflow.com/a/9582409

partition(K, N, 0) :- K > N.

partition(K, N, A+B) :-
 X is K+1,
 Y is N-K,
 partition(X, N, A),
 partition(K, Y, B).
```

`?- partition(1, 10, X).` gives me this:

> X = 1+0+0+0+0+1+(1+0+0)+(1+0+0+0+(1+0))+(1+0+0+0+1+(1+0+0)+(1+0+0+1+(1+0+1)))+(1+0+0+0+0+(1+0)+(1+0+0+1)+(1+0+0+0+(1+0)+(1+0+0+(1+0)))+(1+0+0+0+1+(1+0+0)+(1+0+0+1+(1+0+1))+(1+0+0+0+(1+0)+(1+0+0+(1+0))+(1+0+0+1+(1+0+1)+(1+0+0+(1+0)+(1+0+1+(1+0+(1+1)))))))) ?

One thing that's comforting is that there are indeed 42 ones in the above expression(?).  I was hoping for `X=42.`  Note the question mark.  Yes, there are more matches (apparently infinitely more).  The second one is:

> X = 1+0+0+0+0+1+(1+0+0)+(1+0+0+0+(1+0))+(1+0+0+0+1+(1+0+0)+(1+0+0+1+(1+0+1)))+(1+0+0+0+0+(1+0)+(1+0+0+1)+(1+0+0+0+(1+0)+(1+0+0+(1+0)))+(1+0+0+0+1+(1+0+0)+(1+0+0+1+(1+0+1))+(1+0+0+0+(1+0)+(1+0+0+(1+0))+(1+0+0+1+(1+0+1)+(1+0+0+(1+0)+(1+0+1+(1+(0+0)+(1+1)))))))) ?

Comment: Prolog will not evaluate `A+B` in your `partition(K, N, A+B)` clause head. It is just a term in Prolog. You'll need `partition(K, N, R) :- ... , R is A + B.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I swear this isn't a homework problem. I haven't attended classes in decades.

Calm down, even if it is homework, there is no problem with asking for help given you have done reasonable effort (*reasonable* is of course subjective, but I think it is ok for the question) yourself and it is more that there is a specific problem with your implementation :).

The problem with your approach is that you - among many - think that Prolog attaches semantics to functors. **For Prolog `+` is not plus, nor it add things together**, `+` is simply a symbol, it **does not evaluate it**.

There is however a predicate that evaluates expression trees and uses "semantics" most people agree upon. That is the `is/2` predicate. So now you can simply modify it to:

```
partition(K, N, C) :-
    X is K+1,
    Y is N-K,
    partition(X, N, A),
    partition(K, Y, B),
    C is A+B.
```

> Yes, there are more matches (apparently infinitely more).

That's because your last clause has no *guard* that says `K < N`, in other words Prolog will *backtrack* and regardless on how `K` and `N` relate to each other, it can always pick the last clauses (except for `K == N` since there you placed a cut (`!`)).

You better use a "*guard*" for your last clause since otherwise it can be called if `K < N` when backtracking so. So the full code sequence would read something like:

```
partition(N, N, 1) :- !. %% http://stackoverflow.com/a/9582409

partition(K, N, 0) :- K > N.

partition(K, N, C) :-
    K < N,
    X is K+1,
    Y is N-K,
    partition(X, N, A),
    partition(K, Y, B),
    C is A+B.
```

Note that there is nothing special with `is/2`: it is simply a predicate: you could have called it with `is(C,A+B)` as well. It only is defined in such a way it can be used as infix operator as well.

With the given clauses, the query gives:

```
?- partition(1, 10, X).
X = 42 ;
false.
```

Comment: Why `is(C, A+B)` instead of the more conventional `C is A + B`?

Comment: @lurker: I've added a note at the bottom that the two are equivalent. The aim was to not confuse the OP to think that `is/2` is something special in Prolog. It is simply a predicate that attaches semantics to functors.

Comment: They already have, e.g., `X is K+1`, so I mixing in `is(C, A+B)` could add rather than detract from confusion (the OP could reasonably think, "Why is it different in that case?")

Comment: @lurker: hmm good point. Didn't even noticed the `is` usage (being too much used to it). I've updated the answer and wrote the note in reverse.

Comment: That's better, but why `false`?  And why `false` (`no` on my GNU Prolog install) as a second match?

Comment: I was aware of syntactic sugar, but thanks, @lurker!

Comment: @Lori: well Prolog can give multiple answers on the same query: a function has the property that there is one answer per input tuple, but a predicate can have multiples. After Prolog has found one answer, you can ask if there are more. Prolog says *no*: there is only one answer.