# Inverse factorial in Prolog

Tags: prolog, factorial, clpfd

Can someone helping me to find a way to get the inverse factorial in Prolog...

For example `inverse_factorial(6,X)`   ===>   `X = 3`.

I have been working on it a lot of time.

I currently have the factorial, but i have to make it reversible. Please help me.

Comment: I've added the example.

Answer (score 7):

Prolog's predicates are relations, so once you have defined factorial, you have implicitly defined the inverse too. However, regular arithmetics is moded in Prolog, that is, the entire expression in `(is)/2` or `(>)/2` has to be known at runtime, and if it is not, an error occurs. Constraints overcome this shortcoming:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

n_factorial(0, 1).
n_factorial(N, F) :-
   N #> 0, N1 #= N - 1, F #= N * F1,
   n_factorial(N1, F1).
```

This definition now works in both directions.

```
?- n_factorial(N,6).
   N = 3
;  false.
?- n_factorial(3,F).
   F = 6
;  false.
```

Since SICStus 4.3.4 and SWI 7.1.25 also the following terminates:

```
?- n_factorial(N,N).
   N = 1
;  N = 2
;  false.
```

See [the manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) for more.

Comment: @false. With clpfd in SWI, the query *does* terminate. How come?

Comment: @false. I copy that, but with `?- n_factorial(N,N).` I get `N = 1 ; N = 2 ; false.` As a matter of fact, I *did* get non-termination with some other variant of `n_fac` I coded elsewhere when running the query `?- n_fac(N,N), false.` ... but here? No.

Comment: @false. Good to know! Of course, I didn't doubt that your observation was valid when you made it. I simply couldn't reproduce it. So thank you for the extra effort of investigating several versions.

Comment: This definition works in both directions, and is the most natural and readable way to implement it, but it is extremely slow when searching for the inverse factorial, e.g. `n_factorial(Y, 1000000000)` takes about `20` seconds to answer `false` on my machine.

Comment: @Fatalize: Agreed! There are many ways to improve CLP(FD) programs! The point is just: Should we start from a broken incorrect definition or from a declarative but slow one?

Comment: `n_factorial(N,N).` should terminate in SICStus Prolog 4.3.4 that was released yesterday.

Comment: Thanks false, very informative. Could you provide or point me to a non-clpfd version using successor arithmetics? I can open a separate question if necessary.

Comment: Separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68850347/2326961).

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here is the best implementation of a declarative `factorial` predicate I could come up with.

Two main points are different from @false's answer:

- It uses an accumulator argument, and recursive calls increment the factor we multiply the factorial with, instead of a standard recursive implementation where the base case is `0`. This makes the predicate much faster when the factorial is known and the initial number is not.
- It uses `if_/3` and `(=)/3` extensively, from module [`reif`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl), to get rid of unnecessary choice points when possible. It also uses `(#>)/3` and the reified `(===)/6` which is a variation of `(=)/3` for cases where we have two couples that can be used for the `if -> then` part of `if_`.

#### `factorial/2`

```
factorial(N, F) :-
    factorial(N, 0, 1, F).

factorial(N, I, N0, F) :-
    F #> 0,
    N #>= 0,
    I #>= 0,
    I #=< N,
    N0 #> 0,
    N0 #=< F,
    if_(I #> 2,
        (   F #> N,
            if_(===(N, I, N0, F, T1),
                if_(T1 = true,
                    N0 = F,
                    N = I
                ),
                (   J #= I + 1,
                    N1 #= N0*J,
                    factorial(N, J, N1, F)
                )
            )
        ),
        if_(N = I,
            N0 = F,
            (   J #= I + 1,
                N1 #= N0*J,
                factorial(N, J, N1, F)
            )
        )
    ).
```

#### `(#>)/3`

```
#>(X, Y, T) :-
    zcompare(C, X, Y),
    greater_true(C, T).

greater_true(>, true).
greater_true(<, false).
greater_true(=, false).
```

#### `(===)/6`

```
===(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, T1, T) :-
    (   T1 == true -> =(X1, Y1, T)
    ;   T1 == false -> =(X2, Y2, T)    
    ;   X1 == Y1 -> T1 = true, T = true
    ;   X1 \= Y1 -> T1 = true, T = false
    ;   X2 == Y2 -> T1 = false, T = true
    ;   X2 \= Y2 -> T1 = false, T = false
    ;   T1 = true, T = true, X1 = Y1
    ;   T1 = true, T = false, dif(X1, Y1)
    ).
```

#### Some queries

```
?- factorial(N, N).
N = 1 ;
N = 2 ;
false.          % One could probably get rid of the choice point at the cost of readability


?- factorial(N, 1).
N = 0 ;
N = 1 ;
false.          % Same


?- factorial(10, N).
N = 3628800.    % No choice point


?- time(factorial(N, 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000)).
% 79,283 inferences, 0.031 CPU in 0.027 seconds (116% CPU, 2541106 Lips)
N = 100.        % No choice point


?- time(factorial(N, 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518284253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000)).
% 78,907 inferences, 0.031 CPU in 0.025 seconds (125% CPU, 2529054 Lips)
false.


?- F #> 10^100, factorial(N, F).
F = 11978571669969891796072783721689098736458938142546425857555362864628009582789845319680000000000000000,
N = 70 ;
F = 850478588567862317521167644239926010288584608120796235886430763388588680378079017697280000000000000000,
N = 71 ;
F = 61234458376886086861524070385274672740778091784697328983823014963978384987221689274204160000000000000000,
N = 72 ;
...
```

Comment: So far, you find the optimization for "simple iterative variables" (in lack of a better name) on SO only for simpler cases like `list_length/2`. I wonder if this somehow could be automated!

Comment: @false What do you mean by "the mixing of arithmetic and syntactic equality"? No I do not know about `(#)/1`.

Comment: While `X= 1+0, X#=1` succeeds, `X#=1, X= 1+0` fails. It seems that you have managed to eliminate all such related problems which is surprising indeed. At least the definition I gave had this flaw: `N = 1+1, n_factorial(N,2).` succeeds, but `n_factorial(N,2),N = 1+1.` fails. There is a functor # /1 to overcome this: `#(X)#=1, X=0+1` fails  while `X=0+1, #(X)#=1` is an error. See the manual of clpfd/clpz. This is still somehow tentative, ideally # would be a prefix operator of very low priority, one could then write:  `#X + #Y #= #Z`

Comment: @false When `N` is ground and `F` is free, or when both are free, then it's ok to use `(=)/3`and do `N0 = F` in the then part. But when `F` is ground and `N` is not, then using `(=)/3` on `N` will leave a choice point that is not necessary (the last part of `(=)/3` with `dif`) that we wouldn't get if `F = N0` was the if part. So `(===)/6` allows to fuse both cases, while still having the correct behavior if both `N` and `F` are free. Adding the `=` and `dif` parts for `X2, Y2` is not needed and would actually create redundant results.

Comment: All in all this is a `if_ = or =` situation, that is not completely symmetric (the first `=` being also the situation where both sides are free). The name `===` is not very descriptive I agree, I would have called it `=;=` but this isn't possible.

Comment: `X1=2,===(X1,3,1,1,false,true)` fails, yet `===(X1,3,1,1,false,true), X1=2.` succeeds. Therefore, `=== /6` is not a relation.

Comment: Maybe you need `when((?=(X1,X2) ; ?=(Y1,Y2)), ... )`

Comment: @false Correct. This can be fixed by adding additional cases for `T1 == true` and `T1 == false` because in that case we fall back to the implementation of `(=)/3`. Since I didn't think of a situation where we would call `(===)/6` with `T1` ground, I didn't implement it.

Comment: You need to produce declarative building blocks. Otherwise you are by no means better than purely procedural solutions.

Comment: @false Ideally `(===)/6` shouldn't even exist and a modified version of `if_/3` would be used in that case, so that we don't have to use that `if_/3` in the `then` part.

Comment: I assume you mean `(;)/3` not `if_/3`. But the general problem is even more fundamental than that

Comment: Don't you want to purify your solution? The cheapest way is by using instantiation errors!

Comment: @false I have improved `(===)/6` implementation to fix the type of problem you mentioned.

Comment: `X1 = 1, ===(X1,3,1,1,T,true),T=false.` fails, yet `===(X1,3,1,1,T,true),T=false, X1=1.` succeeds. Non-relational.

Comment: @false This is because `(===)/6` is supposed to be followed by a `if_(T1 = true, X2 = Y2, X1 = Y1)`, in which case it fails correctly in both cases. As I said before, ideally `(===)/6` shouldn't exist and an extension of `if_/3` should be proposed to directly include that second part, which is not in `(===)/6`. Something like `ifeq_or_ifeq(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, (then) X2 = Y2, (or then) X1 = Y1, (else))`.

Comment: You can catch things also with an uninstantiation_error if you like. But your assumptions are easily broken. The point of `if_/3` is that it provides a 100% pure building block and not one that only works in highly specific situations.

Comment: Impressive indeed!

Answer (score 0):

a simple 'low tech' way: enumerate integers until

- you find the sought factorial, then 'get back' the number
- the factorial being built is greater than the target. Then you can fail...

Practically, you can just add 2 arguments to your existing factorial implementation, the target and the found inverse.

Comment: what you think about my solution?

Comment: @SergeiLodyagin: will loop if XFact *isn't* a factorial. Add a test before the recursive call.

Answer (score -3):

Just implement factorial(X, XFact) and then swap arguments

```
factorial(X, XFact) :- f(X, 1, 1, XFact).

f(N, N, F, F) :- !.
f(N, N0, F0, F) :- succ(N0, N1), F1 is F0 * N1, f(N, N1, F1, F).
```

Comment: this doesn't work for X=0, it does not calculate the factorial of number 0.

this is because there's no sucessor of 1 being 0 so it runs out of memory.

Any way to correct it being reversible ?