# Evaluating Factorial

Tags: prolog, factorial

I am trying to write a Prolog function to evaluate the factorial of a Number.

```
factorial(1, 1).
factorial(X, Y) :-
    factorial(A, B),
    Y is B * X,
    A is X-1.
```

The first bit is the base-case, the factorial of 1 is 1.

It works fine for 1! and 2!, but for any number above that it just throws.

```
12 ?- factorial(3,X).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your version does not even work for `1` or `2` as you suggest. And there is `0`, too. You get answers, but you have not asked for the next answer:

```
?- factorial(1, F).
   F = 1
;  error(instantiation_error,(is)/2).
```

So what to do to localize the problem? I will throw in a **`false`**:

```
factorial(1, 1).
factorial(X, Y) :-
    factorial(A, B),
    Y is B * X, false,
    A is X-1.
```

```
?- factorial(2, Y).
   error(instantiation_error,(is)/2).
```

Still same problem. So it must be this very `(is)/2` which is the culprit.

Let's pull the **`false`** even further:

```
factorial(1, 1) :- false.
factorial(X, Y) :-
    factorial(A, B), false,
    Y is B * X,
    A is X-1.
```

There are two remarkable things now: This fragment always loops! And it should be evident why: There is nothing between the head and the recursive goal. Such a situation is called **left recursion**.

And then there is something else that is remarkable: `factorial(A,B)` is called with two uninstantiated variables!  So add this `A is X-1` goal in between, and further ensure that `A > 0`. And add the case for 0.

> > > Some inevitable ceterum censeo: Consider to learn arithmetics with `library(clpfd)` instead. `(is)/2` is soo 1970s. See [the manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) for more! See [Reversible numerical calculations in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896701/reversible-numerical-calculations-in-prolog/2909528#2909528)

Comment: Would give a second +1 for the suggestion that `is/2` *delendam est*. Prolog has both the best and the worst arithmetic support of all languages I've seen.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new to prolog and keep forgetting that I cannot use a variable before it's declared... I'm used to other languages where I can declare variables anywhere in the body of a function. :)

Comment: @DarioP: Welcome! There is no declaration of a variable as such, what is important is to understand how **`false`** "casts" a <s>strike through</s> shadow upon the remaining part of a rule. In this manner you can best observe: Which occurrence a variable is etc.