# factorial by given number in prolog

Tags: prolog, factorial

How can I make a factorial in prolog by a given number ?

```
run:-write('This is a Prolog program that find the factorial of a number'),
start.
start:- nl,nl,write('Please enter the number X = '),read(X),
enterd(X). 
enterd(0):-
write('The factorial of a 0 is '),write('1'),nl.
enterd(X):-
X1 is X-1,
entered(X1,S),
R is S*X,

write('The factorial of the number is'),write(R),nl.
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2909528/772868)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it the usual Prolog way - by defining a recursive rule that covers two clauses:

- When the number is `0`, its factorial is `1` - This can be done with a simple fact.
- When the number is greater than zero, compute `Number-1`, obtain its factorial, and multiplying the result by `Number`.

This should not be too difficult to code up. All you need to know is that arithmetical operations use `is` operator, i.e. `PriorNum is Number - 1` or `Result is Number * PriorFactorial`.

Your `entered/1` predicate looks like an attempt. However, you should rework it into `factorial/2`, with the first parameter representing the input, and the second parameter representing the output of your predicate.

No output should be happening in either of the two clauses - this should be done in the `run` predicate.

```
factorial(0, 1).
factorial(X, R) :- N > 0, X1 is X-1, factorial(X1, S), R is S*X.
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/m2ZP1R)

Comment: really thanks that really help me .i used it in wrong way at first but now it's work

Comment: s(X) for the advise: "no output should be happening in either of the two clauses".