# Reverse factorial with prolog

Tags: prolog, factorial

I was making this program to find the reverse factorial of give number in prolog, but its not working it is returning false everytime. Here is the code.

```
fr(X,Y):-fr(X,2,Y).

fr(X,P,Y):- X =< 1,Y is P-1.
fr(X,Q,Y):-D is X/Q,
      H is X mod Q,
      H =:= 0,
      Q1 is Q+1,
      fr(D,Q1,Y).
```

Here is who this code is supposed to work , it takes 2 argument like this (24,Who). from two argument function I call a 3 argument function ,Which is basically check if the given number is divided by 2 and if it is then it increment in Q and check if the number is divided by 3 and so on.

Comment: `Q is Q + 1` will always fail because you cannot reassign a variable's value. Use `Q1 is Q + 1, fr(D, Q1, Y)` instead.

Comment: Now that the Q is fixed try to solve it. If I thought that was the only problem I would have posted it as an answer rather than a comment. If you're still stuck, then update your question (edit) with the updates code and new, unexpected results.

Comment: its Working, the problem is that i was trying to take mod of D instead of     'code' H is X mod Q 'code',

Comment: The code in the post is working fine , thanks @lurker

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: By the way, you can skip the `H` and just write, `0 =:= X mod Q` and the division, technically, should be integer division: `D is X // Q`, although the check for zero remainder will make it functionally not matter. The integer division keeps `D` an integer. Otherwise, `D` will be a float.

Answer (score 1):

First, take a step back and leave your old code behind. Then proceed like this:

1. Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) instead of plain-old Prolog arithmetic predicates like `is/2` and friends!
2. Focus on the "relational" side of problem solving.

   Look at [this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896701/reversible-numerical-calculations-in-prolog) and the fine answers proposed there.
3. Beware of *premature* optimization!

   Once you *do* know the ins-and-outs of some domain, don't shy away from optimization, either: it can be [great fun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32393749/4609915) and there's a lot to learn, too! (Mind the law of diminishing returns, though.)